# Pipe stream en Nodejs no recibe toda la información

Tags: python, nodejs

estoy trabajando con nodejs y python.

Cuando recibo una petición desde el router de nodejs, lo mando a ejecutar en una tarea de python, se supone que debería esperar a que la ejecución del programa en python acabé para así poder almacenar esa información en una variable y devolverla al front.

Mi código:

```
const wp = async (req, res) => {
    authUser.find({}, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(clc.red(`Error: ${err}`));
        }
        else {
            if (data.find(dbUser => dbUser.login === req.session.login)) {
                console.log('Doing wp');
                let wp = spawn('python3', ['python_tasks/intra.py', 'wp']);
                let dataToSend;
                await wp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                    dataToSend = data.toString();
                });
                await wp.on('close', (code) => {
                    let json = {
                        "status": 200,
                        "message": "success",
                        "spawnCode": code,
                        "data": dataToSend
                    };
                    console.log(json);
                    res.json(json);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

La variable "dataToSend" debería estar al 100% con lo que devuelve el script de python pero sin embargo a veces muestra toda la información o solo la mitad o una cuarta parte de ello.

Alguien sabe cuál podría ser el fallo?, gracias!

Comment: Tengo una duda, según lo que indica el [diccionario de tipos](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/stream.d.ts#L464) y la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream), `ReadableStream.on(...)` no es asíncrono. ¿Probaste usando el constructor `Promise`?

Comment: Es probable que la asignación en `dataToSend = data.toString();` esté pisando los trozos (`chunks`) anteriores. ¿Has pensado en usar: `dataToSend += data.toString();` e iniciar `dataToSend` como una cadena vacía?

Comment: Por otro lado, no hace falta usar `await` de la forma que lo haces allí. Estás trabajando con procesos asíncronos usando `callback`. Tal vez una repasada de la documentación de `streams` de NodeJS sea necesaria. Saludos

Comment: Resuelto, muchas gracias a ambos!

Había problema con el tema de pisar los chunks y con los awaits.